# Highlighting the Text if text is in between two Hash tags ##ccc## text ##234##

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to highlight the text between 2 hash tags with **.greenFlag** class name for all child elements of a **body** tag.

**Ex:**

```
<body>
 <h1>Heading ##New## Item</h1>
 <p> replace ##[any word]## to wrap in [any word] ##Date## </p>
 <p> replace ##any word 2## to wrap in ##any word## some text</p>
</body>
```

**My Code**

```
$('body').children().each(function(){
var content = $(this).text(); 
//content = content.replace(/\##/g, '');
//alert(content);
var str = content.split("##");
$(str).each(function() {
    var term = this;
    alert(term);
    var regex = new RegExp(term, "gi");
    content = content.replace(regex, '<span class="greenFlag">' + term + '</span>');
    $(this).replaceWith(content);
}  
//$(this).text().replace(/\##/g,'<span class="greenFlag">')
```

)});

**Desire Output should be**

```
<body>
 <h1>Heading <span class="greenFlag">New</span> Item</h1>
 <p> replace <span class="greenFlag">[any word]</span> to wrap in [any word] <span class="greenFlag">Date</span></p>
 <p> replace <span class="greenFlag">any word 2</span> to wrap in <span class="greenFlag">any word</span></p>
</body>
```

Please anyone can help me with proper **regular** expressions or any method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
##(.*?)##
```

Replacement string:

```
<span class="greenFlag">$1</span>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bI9fH7/5)